# I am trying to understand this piece of Netsted objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am following a tutorial on YouTube about building projects in Javascript. And this piece of code is supposed to create a Rock, Paper & Scissors game. I understand most part of this code. But my challenge is how the decideWinner function works. How does the variable yourScore pass the value into the rpsDatabase ? and how are the functions being called ?

```js
//Rock, Paper, Scissors

function rpsGame(yourChoice) {
    var humanChoice, botChoice, results, message;

    humanChoice = yourChoice.id;
    botChoice = numberToChoice(randToRpsInt());
    results = decideWinner(humanChoice, botChoice);
    console.log(botChoice);
}

function randToRpsInt () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
}

function numberToChoice (number) {
    return ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'][number];
}

function decideWinner (yourChoice, computerChoice) {
    var rpsDatabase = {
        'rock': {'scissors': 1, 'rock': 0.5, 'paper': 0},
        'paper': {'rock': 1, 'paper': 0.5, 'scissors': 0},
        'scissors': {'paper': 1, 'scissors': 0.5, 'rock': 0},
    };

    var yourScore = rpsDatabase[yourChoice][computerChoice];
    var computerScore = rpsDatabase[computerChoice][yourChoice];

    return [yourScore, computerScore];
}

function finalMessage([yourScore, computerScore]) {
    if (yourScore === 0) {
        return {'message': 'You lost!', 'color': 'red'};
    } else if (yourScore === 0.5) {
        return {'message': 'You tied!', 'color': 'yellow'}; 
    } else {
        return {'message': 'You won!', 'color': 'green'};
    }
}
```

```css
.container-game {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 75%;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.flex-box-weapons {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-box-weapons img:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(37, 50, 233, 1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/style.css">    
    <title>RPS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-game">
        <h2>Challenge 3: Rock, Paper, Scissors</h2>
        <div class="flex-box-weapons" id="flex-box-weapons-div">
            <img id="Rock" alt="Rock" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/rock-clipart-clipart-harvestable-resources-rock.png" width="150" height="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)">
            <img id="Paper" alt="Paper" src="
http://images.clipartpanda.com/paper-clipart-nexxuz-Loose-Leaf-Paper.png" width="150" height="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)">
            <img id="Scissors" alt="Scissors" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/female-hand-sign-victory-sign-peace-sing-scissors-vector-color-flat-illustration-isolated-white-background-web-83128345.jpg" width="150" height="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="content/Js/script.js">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: The `rpsGame` function is called when one of the images are clicked. This happens because each `img` has `onclick="rpsGame(this)"`

Comment: There is nothing special here, both players states hold a single word, and first it picks the list of responses the other player can have based on your input, then it selects the value in that list by using the opponents value. It's nothing more then first selecting an object inside a list, then a value inside that object based on the keys provided. Calling it a 'database' is a bit... much. It's more like a `map` of results. Or a `table`. Think of it as a table.

Comment: be careful, `humanChoice = yourChoice.id;` is related to the `id` attribute of `<img id=...>`. you are using uppercase `id` attribute values, `Rock`, `Paper`, and `Scissors`, but the `rpsDatabase` uses lowercase `rock`, `paper`, `scissors`

Comment: Okay, thank you all so much. I believe that I am not asking the right question. And sorry, I didn't make the question clear. What i want to understand is how **var yourScore = rpsDatabase[yourChoice][computerChoice]; var computerScore = rpsDatabase[computerChoice][yourChoice];** has an effect on the rpsDatabase above it.

@somethinghere

Comment: It has no 'effect' on it, it is just sorting through the first object based on your input, and then sorts the results to find the final score that matches the input on the opponent. All it's doing is "What did the player do?", "Rock" (...searches for rock instruction..), "Okay, now what did the opponent do?", "Scissors", "Okay, let me see..." (..follows listing on instruction sheet..) "Then your score is 1!".

Answer (score 2):

*"How does the variable `yourScore` pass the value into the `rpsDatabase` ?"*

It **doesn't** – `yourScore` is the *result* of looking up a nested value in the database.

You can use a variable to lookup a property of an object using `[]` notation -

```js
const myObject = { hello: "world", foo: "bar" }
const key = "hello"
console.log(myObject[key])
// "world"
```

You can sequence many `[][]...` to lookup a nested property -

```js
const myObject = { hello: { world: "earth" }}
const key1 = "hello"
const key2 = "world"
console.log(myObject[key1][key2])
// "earth"
```

*"And how are the functions being called ?"*

The `rpsGame` function is called when one of the images are clicked. This happens because each `img` has `onclick="rpsGame(this)"`

---

**improvements**

I would like to offer several quality improvements to the code.

**1.** The `rpsDatabase` is redefined each time the `decideWinner` is called. This is unnecessary as the values of `rpsDatabase` do not (should not) ever change -

```js
const rpsDatabase = {
  rock: {scissors: 1, rock: 0.5, paper: 0},
  paper: {rock: 1, paper: 0.5, scissors: 0},
  scissors: {paper: 1, scissors: 0.5, rock: 0},
}

function decideWinner (yourChoice, computerChoice) {
  var yourScore = rpsDatabase[yourChoice][computerChoice]
  var computerScore = rpsDatabase[computerChoice][yourChoice]
  return [yourScore, computerScore]
}
```

**2.** By separating `rpsDatabase`, we can use it to reduce code duplication in `randToRpsInt` and `numberToChoice`. Instead we end up with a simple `randomChoice` function -

```js
function randomChoice () {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  // no need to redefine ["rock", "paper", "scissors"] on each call!
  return Object.keys(rpsDatabase)[rand]
}
```

**3.** The values chose to encode a win, loss, or tie are arbitrary: `1`, `0`, or `0.5`. Consider this alternative -

| outcome | encoding |
| --- | --- |
| win | 1 |
| loss | -1 |
| tie | 0 |

This new `rpsDatabase` would be written as -

```
const rpsDatabase = {
  rock: {scissors: 1, rock: 0, paper: -1},
  paper: {rock: 1, paper: 0, scissors: -1},
  scissors: {paper: 1, scissors: 0, rock: -1},
};
```

Now instead of testing for equality to arbitrary numbers, this allows you to write `finalMessage` in a more natural way using comparisons `>` and `<` -

```js
function finalMessage ([yourScore, computerScore]) {
  if (yourScore > computerScore)
    return {message: 'You won!', color: 'green'}
  else if (computerScore > yourScore)
    return {message: 'You lost!', color: 'red'}
  else 
    return {message: 'You tied!', color: 'yellow'}
}
```

Or the equivalent using `switch`. Maybe you like this form more -

```js
function finalMessage ([yourScore, computerScore]) {
  switch (true) {
    case yourScore > computerScore:
      return {message: 'You won!', color: 'green'}
    case computerScore > yourScore:
      return {message: 'You lost!', color: 'red'}
    default:
      return {message: 'You tied!', color: 'yellow'}
  }
}
```

**4.** Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `onclick` attribute. This creates cleaner separation of HTML and JavaScript, allowing greater portability of both -

```html
<form id="game">
  <button type="button" value="rock"></button>
  <button type="button" value="paper"></button>
  <button type="button" value="scissors">✂️</button>
  <br>
  <output name="result"></output>
</form>
```

```js
const game = document.forms.game

// attach `rpsGame` to `click` event on each `button`
for (const button of game.querySelectorAll("button"))
  button.addEventListener("click", rpsGame)
```

**demo**

Here's a functional demo that incorporates the suggestions above  -

```js
const game = document.forms.game

const rpsDatabase = {
  rock: {scissors: 1, rock: 0, paper: -1},
  paper: {rock: 1, paper: 0, scissors: -1},
  scissors: {paper: 1, scissors: 0, rock: -1},
}

function rpsGame (event) {
  const humanChoice = event.target.value
  const botChoice = randomChoice()
  const result = decideWinner(humanChoice, botChoice)
  game.result.value = JSON.stringify(finalMessage(result))
}

function randomChoice () {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  return Object.keys(rpsDatabase)[rand]
}

function decideWinner (yourChoice, computerChoice) {
  const yourScore = rpsDatabase[yourChoice][computerChoice]
  const computerScore = rpsDatabase[computerChoice][yourChoice]
  return [yourScore, computerScore]
}

function finalMessage ([yourScore, computerScore]) {
  if (yourScore > computerScore)
    return {message: 'You won!', color: 'green'}
  else if (computerScore > yourScore)
    return {message: 'You lost!', color: 'red'}
  else 
    return {message: 'You tied!', color: 'yellow'}
}

for (const button of game.querySelectorAll("button"))
  button.addEventListener("click", rpsGame)
```

```html
<form id="game">
  <button type="button" value="rock"></button>
  <button type="button" value="paper"></button>
  <button type="button" value="scissors">✂️</button>
  <br>
  <output name="result"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: That explains it really well for me. I couldn't understand why he didn't just type in **console.log(myObject[hello][world])** right away, but instead had to use the variables that held the exact strings like the values of the Key1 and key2 variable. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're very welcome! note `myObject["hello"]["world"]` is not the same as `myObject[hello][world]`, notice the absence of quotes. When no quotes are used, `hello` and `world` are seen as variables, and the _value_ of the variables are used as the keys to lookup. However, if you use `.` syntax, you can lookup values without quotes, `myObject.hello.world` will return `"earth"`, as the `.` accepts a property literal, and does not treat `hello` or `world` as variables. Only `[]` can be used to lookup a _variable_ property on an object.

Comment: @StaFa I made an update to this answer that provides many qualitative improvements to the code in your question. I hope you find them useful. Let me know if you have any questions :D

Comment: Yoooo, that's crazy. Because your improvement brought to my attention that the second parameter (computerScore) of the finalMessage function is not being used in the original code. While in your case, you've made use of it and also a lot easier. Thank you so much. The use of const is now something that's firmly imprinted in my brain.

Comment: I have no questions now, but I may have questions in the future, so if it won't be a bother, I'd appreciate you being my mentor.

Comment: Happy to help :D You can feel free to message me whenever. I'm usually on the site several times per week

Answer (score 1):

From your code it is pretty clear that there are three clickable image, when user click either of these images, we are calling a method rpsGame and passing the whole image object as a parameter. This rpsGame method calls another method decideWinner to decide who is the winner by passing two parameters one selected by you(like rock, paper or scissors) and other selected by some random method like numberToChoice.
Finally based on the the result returned by decideWinner method like 0, 0.5 or 1, you can call the finalMessage method and print whatever your results is, based on the condition given in finalMessage method.

Comment: Yes, it helps. I am pretty new to the whole object and especially accessing its key and value. That's why I am confused by all these.